# Enumeration subtype element as parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I have a generic class for which the type must be a subtype of `Enumeration`

```
class MyClass[A<: Enumeration](val parameter1 : Int,
                               val parameter2: A) {

}
```

Inside this class, there is a method that needs to take an element from the enum `A` as parameter. I cannot find the proper way to write the signature of the method.

```
def myMethod(element: A.Values): Resource2[A] = {

    this
}
```

Intellisense says

> Cannot resolve symbol A

How can I write the method so it takes an element of the enum `A` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type is `Value` (not `Values`) and, because `A` is a type and not an instance (i.e. not a value), the syntax for referencing a type within a type is `element: A#Value`.